# Largest element in the set $\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3},...,\sqrt[n]{n}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

What is the largest element in the set $\;\left\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3},...,\sqrt[n]{n}\right\}$?

Once I write down the numbers, it seems like the largest element will be $\sqrt[3]{3}$, but I couldn't come up with an explicit proof.

It looks like the sequence $a_n=\sqrt[n]{n}$ increases up to $n=3$ and then decreases down to $1.$

Comment: One approach using calculus is to study the function $f(x) = x^{1/x} = e^{\log(x)/x}$. You can find where it's increasing, where it's decreasing and where it has it's maximum. Then you will be left with just checking the integers nearest to the maximum.

Comment: Thanks alot Winther. I posted an answer following your hint

Comment: For subsequent questions, it would be best to provide more context (see the above explanation). But here is a proof that may be more instructive than those you have gotten so far: $n \le \sqrt{2}^n$ for every natural $n \ge 4$ (which you can prove by induction). Thus $\sqrt[n]{n} = \sqrt{2}$ for every natural $n \ge 4$. Then compare those $n < 4$.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to answer this without calculus as well. Consider two consecutive terms $\sqrt[n]n$ and $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$, and compare them:
$$
\sqrt[n]n\,?\,\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}\\
n^{n+1}\,?\,(n+1)^n\\
n\,?\,\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\\
n\,?\,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
$$
where the right-hand side is well-known to never exceed $e$ (and even without that, showing that it never exceeds $3$ is not too difficult). So clearly, for $n\geq3$, the question mark will be a $\geq$, meaning all terms after $\sqrt[3]3$ will be smaller than $\sqrt[3]3$.

Answer (score 3):

By the comment and the answer hint which was given I managed to setup the solution. 
Observe that $$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)(1-\ln(x)}{x^2}$$   So the function increases upto $e$ and then decreases from there onwards.
And we can notice that $f(2)=f(4)$ and also both 3 and 4 lie on the decreasing side. Thus $f(3)>f(4)$.
Hence $f(3)$ should be the maximum value.

Comment: It would be preferable to also add the derivation (how you found the maximum was $e$). This makes the answer more useful to others.

Comment: Thanks and I edited

Comment: One parenthesis is missing

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ is increasing wherever $g(x)=\log f(x)$ is increasing. Now
$$
g(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}
$$
and
$$
g'(x)=\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}
$$
Can you finish?